# Score corruption when using computed values to calculate score

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have a use case where:

1. A job can be of many types, says A, B and C.
2. A tool can be configured to be a type: A, B and C
3. A job can be assigned to a tool. The end time of the job depends on the current configured type of the tool. If the tool's current configured type is different from the type of the job, then time needs to be added to change the current tool configuration.

My @*PlanningEntity* is Allocation, with startTime and tool as        @*PlanningVariable*. I tried to add the *currentConfiguredToolType* in the *Allocation* as the @*CustomShadowVariable* and update the *toolType* in the shadowListener's *afterVariableChanged*() method, so that I have the correct *toolType* for the next job assigned to the tool. However, it is giving me inconsistent results.

[EDIT]: I did some debugging to see if the *toolType* is set correctly. I found that the *toolType* is being set correctly in *afterVariableChanged*() method. However, when I looked at the next job assigned to the tool, I see that the *toolType* has not changed. Is it because of multiple threads executing this flow? One thread changing the *toolType* of the tool the first time and then a second thread simultaneously assigning the times the second time without taking into account the changes done by the first thread.

[EDIT]: I was using 6.3.0 Final earlier (till yesterday). I switched to 6.5.0 Final today. There too I am seeing similar results, where the toolType seems to be set properly in *afterVariableChanged*() method, but is not taken into account for the next allocation on that tool.

[EDIT]: Domain code looks something like below:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Allocation {

private Job job;

// planning variables
private LocalDateTime startTime;
private Tool tool;

 //shadow variable
 private ToolType toolType;

 private LocalDateTime endTime;

 @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = TOOL_RANGE)
 public Tool getTool() {
    return  this.tool;
 }

 @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = START_TIME_RANGE)
 public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
    return this.startTime;
 }

 @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ToolTypeVariableListener.class,
        sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(variableName = "tool")})
 public ToolType getCurrentToolType() {
   return this.toolType;
 }

 private void setToolType(ToolType type) {
    this.toolType = type;
    this.tool.setToolType(type);
 } 

 private setStartTime(LocalDateTime startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = getTimeTakenForJob() + getTypeChangeTime();
    ...
 }

 private LocalDateTime getTypeChangeTime() {
 //typeChangeTimeMap is available and is populated with data
    return typeChangeTimeMap.get(tool.getType);
 }
```

}

```
public class Tool {
 ...
private ToolType toolType;
getter and setter for this.

public void setToolType() { ...}

public ToolType getToolType() { ...}

}


public class ToolTypeVariableListener implements VariableListener<Allocation> {
...
@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Allocation entity) {
  scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(entity, "currentToolType");
  if (entity.getTool() != null && entity.getStartTime() != null) {
     entity.setCurrentToolType(entity.getJob().getType());
  }
  scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(entity, "currentToolType");
}
```

[EDIT]: When I did some debugging, looks like the toolType set in the machine for one allocation is used in calculating the type change time for a allocation belonging to a different evaluation set. Not sure how to avoid this.

If this is indeed the case, what is a good way to model problems like this where the state of a item affects the time taken? Or am I totally off. I guess i am totally lost here.

[EDIT]: This is not an issue with how Optaplanner is invoked, but score corruption, when the rule to penalize it based on endTime is added. More details in comments.

[EDIT]: I commented out the rules specified in rules one-by-one and saw that the score corruption occurs only when the score computed depends on the computed values: `endTime` and `toolTypeChange`. It is fine when the score depends on the `startTime`, which is a `planningVariable` alone. However, that does not give me the best results. It gives me a solution which has a negative hard score, which means it violated the `rule` of not assigning the same tool during the same time to different jobs.
Can computed values not be used for score calculations?

Any help or pointer is greatly appreciated.

best,

Alice

Comment: What's your domain code, only for the PlanningEntity and all PlanningVariable and ShadowVariable fields?

Comment: Thank you, @Geoffrey De Smet, added the PlanningEntity, PlanningVariable, ShadowVariable and some other code which we use to calculate the endTime. Maybe thats where I am using Optaplanner incorrectly. Thank you, appreciate your time

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet, I think I know my issue. In the `setCurrentToolType` invoked by `afterVariableChanged`, I am trying to `toolType` of the tool, which in turn is a `PlanningVariable`. So this causes the `PlanningVariable` to change. I think this can cause issues, right? I should look into adding a external `ResourceTracker` or something like that then. Is this thinking accurate?

Comment: So effectively, changes in the shadow variable changes the planning variable, which might explain the score corruption. So to overcome this issue, I need to keep track of the `toolType` of the `tool`, outside the `planningVariable`, via some kind of `ResourceTracker`. Is this the recommended way or can it be tackled some other way? Thank you, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolTypeVariableListener` seems to lack class to the `before/after` methods, which can cause score corruption. Turn on `FULL_ASSERT` to verify.

Comment: I added FULL_ASSERT in the solver config file. It indeed looks like score corruption. I got an IllegalArgumentException saying:

Comment: UndoMove corruption: the beforeMoveScore (-790hard/-1740soft) is not the undoScore (-820hard/-2090soft) which is the uncorruptedScore (-820hard/-2090soft) of the workingSolution.
  1) Enable ... FULL_ASSERT ....
  2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class ...SwapMove). The move ... might have a corrupted undoMove ().
  3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by the score constraints with a different score weight between the beforeMoveScore (-790hard/-1740soft) and the undoScore (-820hard/-2090soft).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "seems to lack class to the before/after methods,". I have all the    before/after entity/variable added/removed/changed   methods, but all the empty except for    afterVariableChanged  . I am using drools for score calculation. The shadow variables are not used for score calculation. Its only used to calculate the endTime. What am I missing here? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I made changes in the afterVariableChanged method. I have updated the code snippet in the question accordingly. The `scoreCorruption` issue went away. I now get another issue:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Variablelistener corruption: the entity (Allocation...)'s shadow variable (Allocation.toolType)'s corrupted value (null) changed to uncorrupted value (...) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.` I checked the code, the setToolType in Allocation is only called in `afterVariableChanged`.

Comment: Optaplanner had tried a few values till this exception was thrown. It then shows up this exception on a value it had tried a bit earlier in the execution cycle.  `Probably the VariableListener class for that shadow variable (Allocation.currentToolType) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed after completedAction` . I saw this:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550460/variablelistener-corruption. I understand that shadow variable needs to be derived from `PlanningVaraible`, but in my case I need it to be based on current job assigned to the tool, for next allocation on tool

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging too, for category org.optaplanner only (with the same config as in the optaplanner-examples logback.xml so you get nice identation so the log is readable), together with FULL_ASSERT and then read the error message and the few log statements just before the exception (probably out of thousands)

Comment: Thank you @Geoffrey De Smet. Did some debugging, found that the score corruption had nothing to do with `toolType` shadow variable or listener implementation. It happens because when I: 1. Add a rule to penalize the score based on the `endTime` (`startTime + toolTypeChangeTime`), so that everything is finished as soon as possible or 2. Add a rule to penalize the score based on the `toolTypeChangeTime`, so as to keep it to a minimum.

Comment: Also, when `toolTypeChangeTime` is not included in the calculation of `endTime`, but calculated nonetheless, there is no score corruption. I do need to penalize the score though.